# Laravel 5 setup git repo for multiple developers

Tags: php, github, laravel-5

I've done lot of Google but still looking for solution, I'm working on Laravel5 project & wants to set it up with GitHub so multiple developer can work on it.

I've install Laravel & place in a repository on Git, Now I cloned it on my local machine & another developer also clone that repository in his machine and start working.

But issue is that, I have installed a package for HTML forms in my machine by composer & push my code to github. But when another developer pull the repository then his code is break because composer.js is updated for that package but actually that HTML package is not exists on his machine.

Can anyone help me to short out this, or is there any way so we ignore vendor folder, composer.js, app.php etc files during git Push?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question specifically, yes you could choose to ignore the vendor folder, composer.json and app.php files when you push to git. To do this, you would simply need to update your `.gitignore` file to reflect this. I.e, include these in your `.gitignore`:

- `/vendor`
- `composer.json`
- `/config/app.php`

But then the next question is whether you really want to do this, as doing so would mean that changes you make - and any subsequent pushes - may not be compatible with work the other developer is doing down the track.

If you exclude the `/vendor` file and the `/config/app.php` file but leave the `composer.json` file in there now that the other developer already has a copy of the core files, the updated `composer.json` file they download would allow them to use `composer install` to update the project with the new package.

However all of this would be problematic for a developer who joins you down the track and doesn't have any of the current files.

Comment: Really thanks for your reply @James, are you talking about .gitignore file which is in root of the application?

Comment: Yep, that's the one @Nipun Tyagi. It should already have some files and directories listed in there. Don't forget to accept the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: Yes Mate, I am just trying it, if it would be working for me that I'll mark it as answer with a up vote too :)

Comment: Given that your other developer already has the updated composer.json file, they will need to either remove it from their end locally or run composer install to install the new package

Comment: You Rocks man ..:) It works but when I added the .evn file in .gitignore to avoid the DB connection overlapping then it updated the .evn file in git repo. Is there any another way to do it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean? Are you wanting to prevent changes you make to your .env locally appearing on github?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93787/discussion-between-nipun-tyagi-and-james).